# How to use selectors when background attribute is used for icon?

Tags: android, css

As you can see, the background attribute is used for a icon, so I cant use drawable selectors on that attribute. I have also tried to use a selector inside a style.xml and use the style attribute to call it, but without any succses.

What can I do?

```
<ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/blackButton"
            android:background="@drawable/black_icon"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:onClick="onButtonClicked"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
```

Comment: is the black_icon drawable an image?

Comment: Yes it is a .png @fixmycode

Comment: Also have a look at [the available type of drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html) you can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your .png drawable inside your selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/black_icon_pressed"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/black_icon_focused"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/black_icon_normal" />
</selector>
```

You will maybe have to create another image from your `black_icon` drawable in order to create the desired effect.

Comment: Allright. I will try that. But isn't that a lot of work if I have many icons and drawable that need selectors(effect) or is it the normal approach?

Comment: what exactly to you want to achieve ? Of course there isn't a single solution. This one is good for few images. If you have plenty we can find a way to to it programmatically. Maybe just edit your question or ask another one to describe exactly what you want to do.